# How do i get data from react hook.?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to get data , from an API and then consume it from another hook component.

But I have this error

This is my App.js

```
 import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import MainRouter from "./core/MainRouter";
import {MovieProvider} from "./context/MovieContext";
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
    const [tagCat,setTagCat] = useState([]);
    const getMovieInfo = async ()=>{
        const res = await axios.get('/get/tag_category');
        //for testing
        setTagCat(res.data.data)
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        getMovieInfo();
    },[]);
  return (
      <MovieProvider value={tagCat}>
          <Router>
            <MainRouter/>
          </Router>
      </MovieProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MovieContext.js

```
    import React, {useContext} from "react";



const MovieContext = React.createContext({});

const MovieProvider = MovieContext.Provider;
const MovieConsumer = MovieContext.Consumer;
export default MovieContext;
export {MovieProvider,MovieConsumer};
```

consume from that PageNav component

PageNav.js

```
    import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import MovieContext,{MovieConsumer} from "../../context/MovieContext";
const PageNav = ()=>{
    const tagCat = useContext(MovieContext);
    const [category,setCategory] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        setCategory(tagCat.main_category);
    })
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <header className="content__title">
                    <h1>Welcome! (Mingalarpar) <small>
                        Feel Free to use any data , btw we need more suggest from  you.
                    </small></h1>
                </header>
                <div className="toolbar">
                    <nav className="toolbar__nav">
                        **{console.log(category[0])}**
                        <a className="active" href="#">Following</a>
                        <a href="groups.html">Groups</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export  default PageNav;
```

I see the data in devtool,
but i cant map the data
i.e.
category.map()//error

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in ContextProvider is fetched asynchronously and hence won't be available on initial render of the component. If you try to set a specific field from it in state of PageNav component, it will throw you can error

You need to check for its existence before using, also you need not store the value obtained from context in state since you can directly derive it

```
const PageNav = ()=>{
    const tagCat = useContext(MovieContext);
    const [category,setCategory] = useState([]);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
               {/* othercode */}
                <div className="toolbar">
                    <nav className="toolbar__nav">
                        {tatCat.main_category && tatCat.main_category.map(() => {})} 
                        <a className="active" href="#">Following</a>
                        <a href="groups.html">Groups</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export  default PageNav;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing object in Context provider in App.js. *value={tagcat}* will be replaced by *value={{tagcat}}* Try this

```js
<MovieProvider value={{tagCat}}>
          <Router>
            <MainRouter/>
          </Router>
 </MovieProvider>
```

Comment: tagCat have below data bro.

{
  main_category:[],
  tags:[]
}

i just try to get main_category in PageNav.js
const {main_category} = useContext(MovieContext())

thank for you answer.